# Error when running the command export PATH=/nsm/bro/bin:$PATH

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I want to install BRO-IDS.

I ran the following commands:

```
cd bro-2.2
./configure --prefix=/nsm/bro
make
make install
```

When I run this command:

```
export PATH=/nsm/bro/bin:$PATH
```

It doesn't work. Is it correct? How do I run this command?

> You can also add PATH=/opt/bro2/bin:$PATH to your ~/.profile file in your home directory to make the change permanent.

I get this error when I try that:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/eng-it/bro-2.2# ~/.profile
bash: /root/.profile: Permission denied
```

and this:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/eng-it/bro-2.2# sudo su -c "echo 'PATH=/opt/bro2/bin:$PATH'>>/etc/profile
```

Doesn't work. Is it correct?

Comment: What does "Do not be operational" mean? Do you mean that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Your first command `export PATH=/nsm/bro/bin:$PATH` is valid in theory, although it's not recommended to prepend to the path - you should append (add to the end) instead.

Have you checked that `/nsm/bro/bin` exists and contains the files you want to run?

Also, the command would only affect the current shell session; the PATH will be unaffected in any other shell (so when you open a new terminal the PATH will not include your addition).

```
root@ubuntu:/home/eng-it/bro-2.2# ~/.profile
bash: /root/.profile: Permission denied
```

This occurs because you are trying to run a file `/root/.profile` which either does not exist or has no execute permission.

If you are root, then the path ~/.profile doesn't lead to your .profile, because `~` expansion is done in reference to the current user. Switch to your normal user and then do

```
nano ~/.profile
```

And then add the lines you want, save and exit.

This command seems valid (although not advisable)

```
root@ubuntu:/home/eng-it/bro-2.2# sudo su -c "echo 'PATH=/opt/bro2/bin:$PATH'>>/etc/profile"
```

`sudo su -c` is redundant since you are already root (why are you root? You should avoid this unless absolutely necessary). However, since you installed the program at `/nsm/bro` according to your `./configure` prefix flag, I don't see why adding `/opt/bro2/bin` to the PATH would help.

Even if that path is correct, you need to log out and log back in for changes made in `.profile` or `/etc/profile` to take effect. To source them instantly, you can start a login shell by typing `bash -l`, or you can source the file you edited `source /etc/profile`

**However**, it is not recommended to add things to `/etc/profile` - you should make a file in `/etc/profile.d`, or specify the variable locally for your user in `~/.profile`.

**Assuming the files you want to run are actually in `/nsm/bro/bin`**, as a normal user (NOT root) You could do

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/nsm/bro/bin' >> ~/.profile
```

or if you really want to set it globally

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 'PATH=$PATH:/nsm/bro/bin' > /etc/profile.d/path.sh'
```

and then log out and log back in.